# Why do nested locks not cause a deadlock?

Tags: c#, asp.net, deadlock

Why does this code not cause a deadlock?

```
   private static readonly object a = new object();
```

...

```
   lock(a)
   {
      lock(a)
      {
         ....
      }
   }
```

Comment: Why are you expecting it to cause a deadlock? (also, this is fairly similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391913/re-entrant-locks-in-c which may help)

Comment: This is clearly a duplicate of that, but this question's title is infinitely better (for people that would likely be seeking it).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If a thread already holds a lock, then it can "take that lock" again without issue.

---

As to *why* that is, (and why it's a good idea), consider the following situation, where we have a defined lock ordering elsewhere in the program of a -> b:

```
void f()
{
    lock(a)
    { /* do stuff inside a */ }
}

void doStuff()
{
    lock(b)
    {
        //do stuff inside b, that involves leaving b in an inconsistent state
        f();
        //do more stuff inside b so that its consistent again
    }
}
```

Whoops, we just violated our lock ordering and have a potential deadlock on our hands.

We *really* need to be able to do the following:

```
function doStuff()
{
    lock(a)
    lock(b)
    {
        //do stuff inside b, that involves leaving b in an inconsistent state
        f();
        //do more stuff inside b so that its consistent again
    }
}
```

So that our lock ordering is maintained, without self-deadlocking when we call `f()`.

Comment: Can you explain why there is a deadlock? Your lock ordering seems consistent to me. 

All code paths lock A OR B->A there is no code path to lock A->B

Comment: @JaredKells It's defined just before the first code block; .... where we have a defined lock ordering **elsewhere in the program** of a -> b:

Answer (score 26):

The `lock` keyword uses a re-entrant lock, meaning the current thread already has the lock so it doesn't try to reacquire it.

A deadlock occurs if

Thread 1 acquires lock A
Thread 2 acquires lock B
Thread 1 tries to acquire lock B (waits for Thread 2 to be done with it)
Thread 2 tries to acquire lock A (waits for Thread 1 to be done with it)

Both threads are now waiting on each other and thus deadlocked.

Comment: Trying to find an example of a non-reentrant lock, but Google is failing me.

Comment: [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an example.

Answer (score 12):

From [section 8.12](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664735%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) of the C# language specification:

> While a mutual-exclusion lock is held,
>   code executing in the same execution
>   thread can also obtain and release the
>   lock. However, code executing in other
>   threads is blocked from obtaining the
>   lock until the lock is released.

It should be obvious that the internal `lock` scope is in the same thread as the outer.