# Nested locking in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm learning multi-threading in C# and I saw a code below

```
static readonly object _locker = new object();

static void Main()
{
  lock (_locker)
  {
     AnotherMethod();
     // ...some work is going on
  }
}

static void AnotherMethod()
{
  lock (_locker) { Console.WriteLine ("Another method"); }
}
```

I wonder when does it require to use nested locking? Why don't use only one lock in this case?

Comment: if `AnotherMethod` is used somewhere else too (and not only in `Main`)...

Comment: The code is truly redundant. The outer lock(_locker) is not necessary. Except if AnotherMethod() would be public and used from somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first response would be that AnotherMethod can be called directly, not going through the Main method, so therefor you might need nested locking.

Answer (score 1):

To allow [re-entrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391913/re-entrant-locks-in-c-sharp) code.

Your example is not appropriate. Locks are used to provide controlled access to [critical section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section).

If one critical section invokes another critical section, then deadlock would occur. To prevent this, re-entrant code is allowed.

[Why do nested locks not cause a deadlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5035177/649524)

Comment: I don't understand the conception of re-entrant code. My code is also re-entrant like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391913/re-entrant-locks-in-c-sharp. When is it going to be used?