# Why doesn't the parent deadlock the child?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

I understand this is a single threaded example and this would lock in a multi-threaded example. But given the execution sequence, shouldn't the lock be consumed by the parent, therefore starving the child even in a single thread situation?

```
class Program
{
    static readonly object Lock = new object();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main start");
        Parent();
        Console.WriteLine("Main end");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Parent()
    {
        lock (Lock)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Parent start");
            Child();
            Console.WriteLine("Parent end");
        }
    }

    static void Child()
    {
        lock (Lock)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Child start");
            Console.WriteLine("Child end");
        }
    }
}
```

Console output

> Main start
>   Parent start
>   Child start
>   Child end
>   Parent end
>   Main end

Comment: ..and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035126/why-do-nested-locks-not-cause-a-deadlock

Answer (score 1):

a thread can acquire a lock again if it is the one who have taken the lock.

> The lock keyword ensures that **one thread does not enter a critical
>   section** of code while **another thread is in the critical section**. If
>   another thread tries to enter a locked code, it will wait, block,
>   until the object is released.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronization simply means two different "threads" can't access the sections that are protected by the same Lock.  However, this is a single thread.  The thread owns the lock, so it is allowed to continue.