# Why doesn't Lock'ing on same object cause a deadlock?

Tags: c#, .net, locking, deadlock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Re-entrant locks in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391913/re-entrant-locks-in-c-sharp)

If I write some code like this:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Foo();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Foo() {
        lock(_lock) {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo");
            Bar();
        }
    }

    static void Bar() {
        lock(_lock) {
            Console.WriteLine("Bar");
        }
    }

    private static readonly object _lock = new object();
}
```

I get as output:

```
Foo
Bar
```

I expected this to deadlock, because Foo acquires a lock, and then waits for Bar to acquire the lock.  But this doesn't happen.

Does the locking mechanism simply allow this because the code is executed on the same thread?

Comment: By the way - it's a bit out of topic but - I think that it's good to know that *"Locks are not magic dust that you sprinkle on code and suddenly it gets safe."*: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix.aspx

Answer (score 95, accepted):

For the same thread a lock is always [reentrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex), so the thread can lock an object as often as it wants.

Comment: +1 The keyword is "reentrant"; a non-reentrant lock (e.g. a file lock) would deadlock.

Comment: Thanks, reentrant was the terminology I lacked, and why I couldn't find an answer to this quickly on Google.

Comment: If a lock can be acquired by a thread more than once, and has to be released that many times, it is called *recursive*. Perhaps not in C# though, but just so you know.

Answer (score 24):

Because you have only one thread here.

`lock` is shortcut for

```
bool lockWasTaken = false;
var temp = obj;
try { 
       Monitor.Enter(temp, ref lockWasTaken); 
       // your thread safe code
}
finally { if (lockWasTaken) Monitor.Exit(temp); }
```

[Monitor.Enter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de0542zz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) acquire the Monitor on the object passed as the parameter. If another thread has executed an Enter on the object but has not yet executed the corresponding Exit, the current thread will block until the other thread releases the object. **It is legal for the same thread to invoke Enter more than once without it blocking**; however, an equal number of Exit calls must be invoked before other threads waiting on the object will unblock.

Comment: +1 for notice about equal number of exit calls before separate thread access permission

Comment: @JaroslawWaliszko re-exiting after re-entering :)

Answer (score 12):

Two words: Reentrant lock.

If a thread has already acquired a lock, then it does not wait if it wants to acquire the lock again. This is very much needed otherwise it could have turned simple recursive functions into a nightmare!

Comment: +1 for recursive common sense

Answer (score 7):

The `lock` statement is smarter than that, and it is designed to prevent just this.  The lock is "owned" by the thread once it gets inside of it, so anytime it reaches another `lock` statement that locks on the same object it will realize that it already has access to that lock.