# Multithreading and Locking (Thread-Safe operations)

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

So I have a class with a few methods which all use locking in order to prevent weird things happening when someone uses an instance of my class with multiple threads accessing it:

```
public class SomeRandomClass
{
    private object locker = new object();

    public void MethodA()
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            // Does something
            MethodB();
        }
    }

    public void MethodB()
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            // Does something else
        }
    }
}
```

As we can see, `MethodB()` is automatically accessed by `MethodA()`, but that won't work since `MethodA()` has currently locked the locker object.

I want to make `MethodB()` accessible publicly, so you can call it manually whenever needed, but I do NOT want it to be used while `MethodA()` is doing things (that's why I'm using a locker object).

And of course I do not want `MethodA()` to do things while `MethodB()` is doing stuff. I basically want only one of all the methods to be used at the same time, but `MethodA()` needs to access `MethodB()` somehow without removing the lock (so that it stays completely thread-safe the whole time).

I really hope it is kind of understandable what I'm trying to ask... If there's any questions about my question, then please go ahead and post them below. Answers/Solutions are very much appreciated as well!

The solution is probably incredibly easy and I'm just not seeing it.

By the way, the above is supposed to be C#-code.

Comment: I removed the java tag.

Comment: So: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think your question is written very clearly and excellently. We don't like "thank you" phrases (they just distract), so I removed the one from your Question.

Comment: Why is b locking locker cuz u r playing around with described dilemma?

Comment: @DrewPierce: Excuse, I really don't understand your question. Would you mind using full words in your probably English comment?

Comment: I will use my microphone on Android so Marcus can understand

Comment: Your code should work just the way it is.
See this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13017319/3495581

Comment: I agree with @Nader, your problem isn't a problem.

Comment: Consider using `akka` futures or similar model for complex systems. Locking makes for lame throughput which will be revealed to you over time.

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution would be to create a **private** method that contains what `MethodB` does that can be called by `MethodA` and another **public** `MethodB`

The **private** `MethodB` does not lock, only the public ones do.

For example:

```
public class SomeRandomClass {

    private object locker = new object();

    public void MethodA {
        lock(locker) {
            // exclusive club
            // do something before calling _methodB
            _methodB();
        }
    }
    private void _methodB {
        // do that, what used to be done by MethodB
    }
    public void MethodB {
        //this one only exists to expose _methodB in a thread-safe context
        lock(locker) {      
            _methodB();
        }
    }
}
```

---

P.S.

I think it is obvious to you and everyone else why your code is somewhat *designed* to create a deadlock.

---

**Update**:

Apparently `lock(object) {}` is [re-entrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex) as pointed out in the comments, so the obvious deadlock isn't even one.

Answer (score 0):

Locking forbids what you're trying to do -- that's its purpose.

One thing to do here is creating a private method that you can access from both `methodA` and `methodB`. That method wouldn't use locking, and wouldn't be thread safe, but could be called from either one of the locking methods.

Comment: Well, just don't spam :) Especially together with a discussion of your problem or the answer, this is absolutely OK.

Answer (score 0):

You have race condition here: it make data incorrect. I suppose method A write static `theVar` variable of type string:

```
thread A -> call method A -> lock -> change theVar to "A"
thread B -> call method B -> wait because thread A keep lock
thread A -> release lock to call method B
    The bug here: thread B process theVar of "A"
    If method B only read theVar, it's Ok.
```

Comment: Perhaps Marcus can help wordsmith this

Comment: @AsConfused, yes I think so.

Answer (score 0):

Your lock mechanism needs to allow locks to be taken in a recursive way (by the same thread only), usually called `reentrant`. `lock` ([Monitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor(v=vs.110).aspx) class internally).

> It is legal for the same thread to invoke Enter more than once without it blocking; however, an equal number of Exit calls must be invoked before other threads waiting on the object will unblock.

See also [Recursive / nested locking in C# with the lock statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687505/recursive-nested-locking-in-c-sharp-with-the-lock-statement)
and [Re-entrant locks in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391913/re-entrant-locks-in-c-sharp)

As pointed out by Henk Holterman in the comment, the `Monitor` class is already reentrant. And the `lock` statement is managing the right amount of `Enter` and `Exit` calls to the underlying `Monitor` class.

The `ReaderWriterLockSlim` class is an example for a lock mechanism where one can choose between `reentrant` and `non-reentrant`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx

`var rwLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim(LockRecursionPolicy.SupportsRecursion);`

Replace your `lock { ... }` with

```
ReaderWriterLockSlim rwLock = 
    new ReaderWriterLockSlim(LockRecursionPolicy.SupportsRecursion);

...

try 
{
    rwLock.EnterWriteLock();
    // Does something
}    
finally 
{
    rwLock.ExitWriteLock();
}
```

```

Comment: Commenting why "This ansewer is not useful" would be nice and helpful to me.

Comment: Your first paragraph starts Ok but then you draw the wrong conclusions. Look at the text you quoted, `lock(){}` is re-entrant in exactly the simple way that is needed here. No workaround required.

Comment: I´v read over it again, you are right. Lock/Monitor is already reentrant

Answer (score 0):

The Code written by you is correct.

Because according to Microsoft, once the call is acquired even if program calls for lock in the same flow, it will not be blocked as lock is already with the thread. 
The code works as below.

1. call "MethodA" -->acquire lock --> call "MethodB" (will not be blocked as thread is already acquired lock) and execution will be completed.
2. Call "MethodB" in between previous execution from another thread, the execution will be blocked as lock is with first thread.