# How to make a method which only runs if the calling thread holds a lock?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, c#-3.0

In my unsafe class below, what can be done to prevent someone from executing the unsafe method without first obtaining the lock?

```
class Unsafe
{
    private static readonly object lockObj;

    void MethodA()
    {
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            // do some things
            DoUnsafeThing();
        }
    }

    void MethodB()
    {
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            // do some things
            DoUnsafeThing();
        }
    }

    void DoUnsafeThing()
    {
        if (callerHasLock)
            // Do the unsafe thing
        else
            return; // or throw some exception
    }
}
```

Obtaining the lock again inside `DoUnsafeThing()` is an option:

```
void DoUnsafeThing()
{
    lock (lockObj)
    {
        // Do the unsafe thing
    }
}
```

But `DoUnsafeThing()` can now be called by threads that don't already possess the lock.

Comment: As it is currently written, this would allow only a single thread to perform the `DoUnsafeThing()` method at a time. I'd probably move the lock to within that method, but otherwise looks fine. It you want it to be locked per thread, put `[ThreadStatic]` on the lock object.

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't put the lock in `DoUnsafeThing`, and only in `DoUnsafeThing`. There are other types of things you can use instead of lock (like `Monitor.TryEnter`) that would fail rather than wait if there is already a lock on it.

Comment: @DavidHaney - why make the lock object ThreadStatic? Doesn't that defeat the whole purpose of locking?

Comment: @hatchet: `MethodA` and `MethodB` are mutually unsafe throughout, and they contain an amount of duplicate code which I'd like to factor out into `DoUnsafeThing`. In hindsight, this was not clear in my question.

Comment: @hatchet yeah, in hindsight that's moronic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use [Monitor.IsEntered()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.isentered%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to verify that the thread itself has already obtained the lock:

```
void DoUnsafeThing()
{
    if (Monitor.IsEntered(lockObj))
        // Do the unsafe thing
    else
        return; // or throw some exception
}
```

You can use the `Monitor` class to work with locks.  In C#, the `lock(...)` statement is just syntactic sugar for `Monitor.Enter(o); try {...} finally {Monitor.Exit(o);}`.  There are other options within it for fine-tuning.  Remember, multi-threading is Hard.  Know your toolset.

**EDIT:** (in response to framework version question update)

Prior to .NET 4.5, AFAIK the only way to handle this would be to use a thread-static Boolean alongside the synchronization object, set to `true` just after entering and `false` just before exiting.  That same Boolean--call it `callerHasLock`, to conform with your code above--can then be tested within the lock context with the same result as `Monitor.IsEntered`.

Comment: I've voted this up (thanks!), but I'm going to hold off on marking it correct until I've translated a solution available in C# 3.5.

Comment: @NiloCK `Monitor` has been around since .NET 1.1

Comment: You could do something similar to what Marc has suggested, but use Monitor.TryEnter which is in 3.5. A thread should be able to lock the same object twice.

Comment: Ahh, the *method* is missing in 3.5 - I'm really off my ball on this question... ;)

Comment: @DavidHaney: The particular method `IsEntered` is new. @hatchet: That ought to do the trick.

Comment: @hatchet, I'm thinking that may not work, since like `Enter`, `TryEnter` communicates whether _any_ thread holds a lock on the lock-object--if not, it returns `true` whether the monitor is just- or already-entered.

Comment: @NiloCK - see this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391913/re-entrant-locks-in-c-sharp Just using plain `lock` in the three methods may work fine if waiting is fine, and `TryEnter` if you want failure if lock not already obtained.

Comment: @NiloCK, please update your question and tags to reflect that dependency.

Comment: @hatchet, the problem is that neither `Enter` nor `TryEnter` will preclude (or help to preclude) an otherwise un-blocked thread from entering the meat of `DoUnsafeThing()` _if it had not previously obtained the lock_, which is precisely what is desired here.